# alter system flush shared_pool oracle

Tags: oracle, system, flush, alter

I've two questions
First, it's substantial the difference between execute the ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL command in the server and in one client? In my company they teach me that I've to execute directly in the server that command, but I think is just a command that goes for the network and just a message that is flushed I think that shouldn't be substantial differente how it happens with lot of data, I'm talking of a system that take about 5 minutes approximately to flush

The second, how can I flush a instance from another instance?

Comment: You make it sound like running that command is something you do regularly.  But you (or the DBA actually) really should only run that command under very extreme circumstances only.  I really hope you're not doing that in production, as it's basically a performance killer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL;` can be run from either the client or the server, it doesn't matter.

Many DBAs will run the command from the server, for two reasons.  First, many DBAs run *all* commands from the server, usually because they never learned the importance of an IDE.  Second, the command `ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL;` only affects one instance in a clustered database.  Connecting directly to the server is usually an easy way of ensuring you connect to each database instance of a cluster.

But you can easily flush the shared pool from *all* instances without directly connecting to each instance, using the below code.  (Thanks to [berxblog](http://berxblog.blogspot.com/2017/04/can-i-flush-shared-pool-of-all-rac.html) for this idea.)

```
--Assumes you have elevated privileges, like DBA role or ALTER SYSTEM privilege.
create or replace function flush_shared_pool return varchar2 authid current_user as
begin
    execute immediate 'alter system flush shared_pool';
    return 'Done';
end;
/

select *
from table(gv$(cursor(
    select instance_number, flush_shared_pool from v$instance
)));

INSTANCE_NUMBER   FLUSH_SHARED_POOL
---------------   -----------------
1                 Done
3                 Done
2                 Done
```

I partially disagree with @sstan - flushing the shared pool should be rare in *production*, but it may be relatively common in *development*.  Flushing the shared pool and buffer cache can help imitate running queries "cold".

Comment: I`m a junior DBA, we do some tasks from the client,  but that task in especific from the server, how can I test if they are really a significant difference, I mean do the flush take a time that I can notice, and the second cuestion I was especting an answer like that, but just in the same command something like ALTER KILL SESSION `130,620,@2`;

Comment: It's going to be tricky to test, because the second time you run the command it will likely be much faster.  You may need to run it once a day, alternating between running on the client and the server, repeat that X times, then average the run times.  But I wouldn't even bother testing it - I can't imagine *why* that command would take longer depending on where it's run.  I've *never* seen a command run slower on a client unless it was transferring data, and this command won't transfer data.

Comment: I will look a way to load the shared buffer a lot more quickly and equally every time.. And see if they are parameters to change to do it harder to flush